# How to call a function from Oracle on C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I want to execute the following Oracle function and return its value in a C# method:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function days (fulldays int, halfdays int)
return int is daysResult int; 
BEGIN  
daysResult:= ((fulldays * 8) + (halfdays * 4)); 
return (daysResult);
END days;
```

C# code:

```
 public double days(int fulldays, int halfdays)
        {
                OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "days";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("fulldays", fulldays);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("halfdays", halfdays);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("daysResult", OracleDbType.Int32);
                cmd.Parameters["daysResult"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var result = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["daysResult"].Value);
                MessageBox.Show(result); //----shows null value
                return Convert.ToDouble(result);
        }
```

I want to retrieve the value returned in the Oracle function and return it to the C# method as well, but the MessageBox ends up showing blank whenever C# 'days' method is called.

Comment: I guess `cmd.Parameters.Add("daysResult"...` must be the first parameter, not the last one.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit this solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: If this isn't a dup, then you should write your comment up as an answer.  It would be good for the next person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of parameters is wrong. The return parameter must be the first one:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("daysResult", OracleDbType.Int32);
cmd.Parameters["daysResult"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add("fulldays", fulldays);
cmd.Parameters.Add("halfdays", halfdays);
```